# Get Form value of selected Select Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To begin, I have put a form in to a for loop. In this form there is also a Select tag available. When the option in the select box is changed, I should get a form serialize where the selected Select tag is. The coding:

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<5; $i++)
{
?>
<form action="#" method="post" id="designer_status_frm_1">
                <select style="font-size: 8pt; height: 20pt" class="form-control" id="status_job_decigner_1" name="status_job">

        <?php  
        $sqlstatus="SELECT * FROM `designer_status_options`";
        $stmtstatus=$dbg->query($sqlstatus);
        foreach($stmtstatus as $rowstatus) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rowstatus['status_id'];?>" <?php if($rowstatus['status_id']==$status_row['status_id']){echo 'selected'; }?>><?php echo $rowstatus['status'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>

      </select>
                <input type="hidden" name="lg_user_id" id="lg_user_id" value="<?php echo $status_row['designer_id']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="job_id_info" id="job_id_info" value="<?php echo $status_row['job_pro_id']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="add_status">
            </form>
            <?
            }
            ?>
```

How can i get this form value in jquery?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post rendered code here

Comment: `$("select").val()` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#status_job_decigner_1').val();
```

Is how you would get the value using the id along with jQuery.

If you want the value on change, you could do

```
$('#status_job_decigner_1').change(function() {
    var select_value = $(this).val();
}
```

To serialize the form on change, just add

```
var form_data = $('#designer_status_frm_1').serialize();
```

to the change event for the select.

To serialize the form for the changed select, you could do

```
$('#status_job_decigner_1').change(function() {
    var select_value = $(this).val();

    var form_data = $(this).parents('form').serialize();
    // or $(this).closest('form').serialize();
}
```

Comment: When more then 1 Form are there with same name and id. So i want only serialiaze the form whick the selection box  value was change. In javascript in Onchange function.

Comment: @sanji - I've updated the answer which should work (haven't tested). The same name is fine but the id attribute must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)** or **[`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)** for getting form data

```js
$('#status_job_decigner_1').change(function() {
  var select = $(this).val();
  // To get select value
  var form = $('#designer_status_frm_1').serialize();
  // To get serialized form value
  var formArr = $('#designer_status_frm_1').serializeArray();
  // To get serialized array form value

  console.log(select, form, formArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="designer_status_frm_1">
  <select style="font-size: 8pt; height: 20pt" class="form-control" id="status_job_decigner_1" name="status_job">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="lg_user_id" id="lg_user_id" value="<?php echo $status_row['designer_id']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="job_id_info" id="job_id_info" value="<?php echo $status_row['job_pro_id']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="add_status">
</form>
```

Comment: ok but i have more then one form with the same name in loop. So how can get the Changed selection box's Form serlialized?

Comment: first of all id should be unique, you can access it by `$(this).closest('form')`

Comment: @sanji `$(this).closest('form').serialize()` or `$(this).closest('form').serializeArray()`